# When rendering, Cycles and Eevee only renders some materials

Tags: rendering, materials

I was following along with a tutorial and finally finished my first model, when I try to render however it only renders some of the materials.

The render I get.
[image: This is the render I get]

Screenshot of the materials that go missing.
[image: These are some example materials I applied]

[Sword.blend1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lLTlSg3zgJo_rCSN20CBqibBD0UzzlKt/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: hello, could you please tell what material are you talking about? Also, if it has to do with an image texture maybe pack the images into the file before sharing (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend)

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure the materials go missing. Are you talking about what look like reflections of the surroundings on the sword? I have repeatedly thought something was wrong with my metallic materials when that happened in material preview but disappeared in render, but it turns out that’s just because the world background in the material preview is automatically an HDR texture, and in cycles or EEVEE render it defaults to flat gray which makes no reflections.

Just change the World background to something interesting (an environment texture from blender’s own data files works great) and metallic materials should look much better .

As for the glow effect, this is likely because you enabled bloom while using EEVEE, but then switched to cycles render. The bloom will still appear in material preview. You can create a bloom like effect for cycles using the glare node in the compositor .

Comment: Thanks! This worked wonderfully